# BrowserFS starting file path to point on local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, browserfs

I am using `BrowserFS` for browser file system.

```js
    var fs = ''
    var path = ''
    BrowserFS.install(window)
    BrowserFS.configure({ fs: 'LocalStorage' }, err => {
      if (err) {
        alert(err)
      } else {
        fs = window.fs = window.require('fs') // also tried BrowserFS.BFSRequire('fs')
        path = window.path = window.require('path') // also tried BrowserFS.BFSRequire('path')
      }
    })
```

Then I tried calling it like this:

```js
    console.log(process.cwd())
    console.log(__dirname)
    fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(process.cwd())).forEach(file => {
      console.log('file: ' + file)
    })

    fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '..//defaults')).forEach(file => {
      console.log('__dirname file: ' + file)
    })
```

Then I get the following errors and log outputs:

```
/
/
file: test.txt sample-xml-upload.vue:145
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/defaults'"
```

so:

```
    console.log(process.cwd()) // results to /
    console.log(__dirname) // results to /
```

How can I make the path look at the actual local location where the file is called (ex. `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\NodeJS`)?

Help please!

Thanks!